# compact convergence on a non-compact metric space implies continuity: part 2

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness, uniform-convergence

This is the sequel to [compact convergence on a non-compact metric space implies continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331271/compact-convergence-on-a-non-compact-metric-space-implies-continuity).

$\textbf{Proposition: }$Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces. Let $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ which is pointwise convergent to some $f:X\to Y$. If $X$ is not compact, but the convergence $f_n \to f$ is uniform on every compact subset of $X$, then $f$ is continuous.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ We know that if the convergence $f_n\to f$ is uniform on $K\subset X$, then $f$ is continuous on $K$.

Choose $a\in X$. We will prove that $f$ is continuous in $a$. Since $\{a\}$ is a compact set of $X$, the convergence $f_n\to f$ is uniform on this set. Hence $f$ must be continuous in $a$.

This proof seems too easy to be true, yet it is completely the same as [compact convergence on a non-compact metric space implies continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331271/compact-convergence-on-a-non-compact-metric-space-implies-continuity). Is this wrong?

Comment: It is. You've proven that the map $f$ restricted to the singleton $a$ is continuous. This does not imply continuity. What you need is the assumption that $X$ is locally compact, so that every point has a neighbourhood which is compact. Otherwise, the proposition is, to my knowledge, not true.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, the proposition is true. See the proof in the link to my first question. Also, yes, of course. Thank you.

Comment: Right... in the metric space setting, I guess it is true.